# Help need in creating a hashset from a hashmap

Tags: java

I've been able to read a four column text file into a hashmap and get it to write to a output file. However, I need to get the second column(distinct values) into a hashset and write to the output file. I've been able to create the hashset, but it is grabbing everything and not sorting. By the way I'm new, so please take this into consideration when you answer. Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what the relationship to Javascript is? I'm assuming you're really talking about Java, given the class names.

Comment: Apparently, I'm the only one bold enough to just go ahead and remove the tag. :)

Comment: What exactly are you putting in the HashMap? Are you using the text of one column as the key? What are you putting as the value? The concatenation of all the remaining columns?

Comment: Sorry about the mix up, false alarm for Javascript.

Comment: I am inputting four columns(ListID, Name, ListPrice, NameID). The NameID is my unique value. I want to retrieve the name once even though it maybe inserted multiple times.

Comment: @user442471: You mentioned showing us some code... but you haven't done so.

Answer (score 4):

Neither [`HashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) nor [`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) are *meant* to sort. They're fundamentally unsorted data structures. You should use an implementation of [`SortedSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html), such as [`TreeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Comment: +1 for being correct (and technically, 35 seconds before my now deleted answer)

Comment: I've implemented a treeset but i am still getting everything and the sort doesn't seem to be taking place. I think my placement of the treeset or implementation maybe the issue. Sample below of how I'm using it.

Answer (score 1):

Some guesses, related to mr Skeets answer and your apparent confusion...

Are you sure you are not inserting the **whole line** in the TreeSet? If you are going to use ONLY the second column, you will need to split() the strings (representing the lines) into columns - that's nothing that's done automatically.

Also, If you are actually trying to sort the whole file using the second column as key, You will need a **TreeMap** instead, and use the 2:nd column as key, and the whole line as data. But that won't solve the splitting, it only to keep the relation between the line and the key.

Edit:  Here is some terminology for you, you might need it.

You have a `Set`.  It's a collection of other objects - like `String`. You `add` other objects to it, and then you can fetch all objects in it by `iterating` through the set. Adding is done through the method `add()`and iterating can be done using the enhanced `for loop` syntax or using the `iterator()` method.

The set doesn't "grab" or "take" stuff; You `add` something to the set - in this case a `String` - Not an array of Strings which is written as `String[]`

(Its apparently possible to add array to a TreeSet (they are objects too) , but the order is not related to the contents of the String. Maybe thats what you are doing.)

```
String key = splittedLine[1]; // 2:nd element
```

"The second element of the keys"  doesn't make sense at all.   And what's the duplicates you're talking about. (note the correct use of apostrophes... :-)

Comment: I am splitting the strings and taking only the second element. It seems when i use the treeset it is taking the second element of each of the key's. I think this is why i'm seeing the duplicates. I really just want the value once. As you stated, it is keeping the relation between the line and the key. This is how i'm splitting below.                                                        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\s]+");
 String[] str = p.split(strLine);

Comment: @user442471: What You are saying doesn't really make sense... Edit your question to show the code, and we'll try to explain whats going on.